# could not find function "hc_add_series_density" Highcharter R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm using Highcharter version 0.6.0 (R)

I need to build density plots and each plot needs to have multiple series. 
I looked up online and came across hc_add_series_density by Nuno Agostinho.

I tried using it in the code below but i get the error - "could not find function "hc_add_series_density""

```
library(highcharter)
library(magrittr)

set.seed(1) 
x <- rbeta(300, 0.2, 4) 
y <- rbeta(300, 0.5, 4) 

hcdensity(x, area = TRUE) %>% 
    hc_add_series_density(y, area = TRUE)
```

Is it not there in version 0.6.0 ? If not, how can I achieve density plots with multiple series ?

Thank You

Comment: Have you installed it with ```install.packages('highcharter')```?

Comment: Please show a reproducible example of the code that produces this error.

Comment: @RussThomas, yea! i used "install.packages("highcharter")"

Comment: @Marius `set.seed(1)
x <- rbeta(300, 0.2, 4)
y <- rbeta(300, 0.5, 4)

hcdensity(x, area = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_add_series_density(y, area = TRUE)` this gives the above mentioned error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function `hc_add_series_density`, there's a method `hc_add_series.density`, but you usually wouldn't call it directly. Instead, you'd just call `hc_add_series` on a `density` object, and the appropriate method will be called, e.g.:

```
hcdensity(x, area = TRUE) %>% 
    hc_add_series(density(y), area = TRUE)
```